# How to fix CMake Error Could NOT find OpenSSL missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY when configuring Azerothcore

Tags: cmake, openssl, azerothcore, cmake-gui

When I'm trying to configure CMake in order to build Azerothcore I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY Crypto
  SSL) (found version "3.2.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/macros/FindOpenSSL.cmake:559 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/openssl/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
```

I added following system variables (because I didn't have them) and CMake entries:

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib
OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64
```

it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing 3.0.12 version